# Unexpected form url with mixed aspx & controller MVC .Net routes

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes defined thus:

```
//Custom route for legacy admin page
      routes.MapPageRoute(
       "LocaliseRoute",                         // Route name
       "Admin/Localise",                // URL
       "~/Views/Admin/Localise.aspx"   // File
       );

routes.MapRoute(
       "Admin", // Route name
       "Admin/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

both the following GETs work fine:

```
http://pegfect.local/Admin/PegModelUpload
http://pegfect.local/Admin/Localise
```

However, the form action of the former is `/Admin/Localise?action=UploadPegModel&controller=Admin`

resulting in an expression of "WTF?!"

the code for the form is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPegModel", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return validateForm();" }))
{
  <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right here: http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/combining-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet.html

Answers on a postcard as to why this would work...